# Inject Log4Net into console application using Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, log4net

Is there an article or complete example showing how to inject Log4Net logger into a console application using ninject? I have so far managed to create a new instance in the main module but am not able to figure out how to inject. Below is sort of the set-up I have.

Edit: Thought I would add the reason behind doing this too. I wanted to inject the logger into the other classes to do logging.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Modules;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public class MyProgram
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
            log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

            try
            {
                log.Info("Application - Start");

                Initialiase();

                _something.DoSomething();

                log.Info("Application - End");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Application failed", ex);
            }
        }

        private static void Initialiase()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            _something = kernel.Get<ISomething>();
        }
    }

    public class Bindings : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ISomething>().To<Something>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see where you're using your `Bindings` object... is it from the `kernel.Load()` call and if it is, is it actually running your `Load()` method?

Comment: Yes, Bindings.Load() overrides NinjectModule.Load(). Yes, it runs my Bindings.Load() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I achieved it...

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Ninject;
using log4net;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public class MyProgram
    {
        private static ILog _log;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Initialiase();

                _log.Info("Application - Start");

                _something.DoSomething();

                _log.Info("Application - End");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error("Application failed", ex);
            }
        }

        private static void Initialiase()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            _log = kernel.Get<ILog>();
            _something = kernel.Get<ISomething>();
        }
    }

    public class Bindings : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(c => LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program))).InSingletonScope();
            Bind<ISomething>().To<Something>();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can DI ILog and start logging.

However, the logger now always has the name SomeNameSpace.Program. This would make it difficult to identify where the logs are getting written from in the application. The easiest solution I could find to that was to change the Log4Net config and use %C in place of %logger.

Hope this helps.